# Why is SENTRI more expensive than Global Entry?

Tags: usa, tsa, global-entry

According to http://www.dhs.gov/comparison-chart membership in the SENTRI program costs $122.25 for five years whereas membership in the Global Entry program costs $100 for 5 years. This doesn't make any sense to me.

Doesn't Global Entry do everything that SENTRI does and then some? Or does SENTRI offer perks that Global Entry doesn't?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While the benefits are similar, they are different.  Global Entry is limited to US citizens & permanent residents and citizens of 5 or 6 other countries.  SENTRI is available to any citizen of any country as long as they are admissable to the US.

Global Entry requires passport to apply, SENTRI does not.

One might guess that the expanded coverage of SENTRI warranted a higher price in CBP's judgement.

Answer (score 11):

The programs are designed for different purposes, function differently internally, and thus have different costs.

For instance, SENTRI was designed specifically for use at the Mexican land border, and most people who have a SENTRI card are U.S. or Mexican citizens who cross this border frequently.

On the other hand, Global Entry is only really useful at airports, where it expedites entry by allowing people to scan their passport at a kiosk rather than talk to an officer for immigration check (though of course everyone still goes through customs). There are no such kiosks at land borders.

Also of note, for many people Global Entry has largely been superseded by other programs, such as Automated Passport Control (which lets US and Canadian citizens and repeat VWP travelers also use kiosks for immigration control) and Mobile Passport Control (which lets US and Canadian citizens do immigration control from their smartphones), both of which are free.

Comment: That's pretty cool, do you happen to know if they're widely available in the US yet ? At least major airports ?

Comment: @blackbird57 Perhaps if you could tell me what you are referring to when you say "they"?

Comment: Automated Passport Control, sorry. I saw those in Vancouver, I think before only Canadian citizens could scan their passports and skip the regular immigration line

Comment: @blackbird57 Erm, yes? https://www.google.com/search?q=automated+passport+control&btnI=

Comment: Right then, search before asking, sorry :)

Comment: Note that you can now use Global Entry as a pedestrian at some land borders if you have the physical Global Entry card with you. You still can't use the SENTRI vehicle lanes of course unless you're enrolled in SENTRI.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the SENTRI lanes at the US-MEX (as well as NEXUS lanes at US-CAN)  land border with the Global Entry RFID card that they send you (if flying it's just your passport, no card). CBP also does not require a vehicle inspection anymore to register your car for it, at least if you do it with your application. If registering it later, I'm not sure (but it costs like $40 to then anyways).

Answer (score 1):

I cross from Mexico to the US using a Sentri pass. My wife crosses, with me, through the Sentri lane with a Global Entry pass. You are required to have your car inspected one time. I understand that with a Global Entry, you are now able to have your car inspected. Not applicable if you are walking across.